# What is the correct syntax for this json/jquery call?

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, syntax

I am using phonegap and have a search on the page. The id in the form is mysearch and should be placed at the end of the $.get call. I know the call is correct because I can put it in a browser and get the required output in json format. The problem is that what I type in form is not ending up into the call. I may not have the syntax correct at the end of the call. Any help would be really appreciated. The form code and the call are below.

```
    <form action="searchresult.html" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="mySearch" id="mySearch" data-mini="true" data-   theme="b" style="color:#888;"
    value="" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
    </form>

    <script>
     $("#resultPage").live("pageshow", function (){
       $.get("http://www.test.net/jquery/test.cfc?method=getsearch&returnformat=json&searchName=" + $("#mySearch").val(), {},  function(res) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use .on insted .live (because this method are deprecated)

```
  $.get("YOUR URL", function(res) {
   // implement logical
}, 'JSON').error(function(){
   alert('Http error'); // protocol error like 404
});
```

Comment: I tried changing it to .on instead of .live but that did not work either. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery-1.7.2.min.js.

Comment: Try this test `$('#resultPage').on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
console.info(event);
console.info(ui);
});`
This event are triggered?

Comment: I have the same type of call being used several times in this app and I have not had any problems. I would like to try your suggestion but I am a beginner at coding. I am not certain what I should put for the (event,ui). Is this the same as the call? I apologize for my confusion. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Run this code in your app using Chrome, press F12 (In Windows Case)  to see Console tool and catch this output from console.info() - searching for "pageshow", I found a lot of ocurrencies about this problem.